# How to replace onsubmit/onclick for Password Generator Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension for my Grad-Project trying to make a password manager
i got password generator but the big problem that Broweraction doesn't support onsubmit or onclick
i'm trying to create something like onepassword and lastpass extensions so i'm wondering how the the generator is working in the broweraction

```
 <form  method="get"  name="passform" onsubmit="generate();javascript:passInBox(); return false;">
   <p>
      Choose Length: 
      <select id="length" style="padding:0.2em 1.5em;font-family:monospace; font-size: 16px">
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="11">11</option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="13">13</option>
         <option value="14">14</option>
         <option value="15">15</option>
      </select>
   </p>
   <p style="margin-top:0.5em; line-height:1.5"><input type="radio" id="alphabetic" checked="checked" name="type"> <label for="alphabetic">Alphabetic</label><br>
      <input type="radio" id="alphanumeric"  name="type"> <label for="alphanumeric">Alphanumeric</label><br>
   <p><input id="Gbutton" type="submit" value="Generate password" id="show" style=" " onClick=                                      \""></p>
   <p><input type="password"  id="result"  name="passbox" tabindex="1" size="20"> 
   <div style="font-size:14px ;margin-bottom:15px; ">
      <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('result').type = this.checked ? 'text' : 'password'"> show or hide password 
   </div>
   </p>
   <p><input  class="buttons" type="reset" value="Clear" >&nbsp;
      <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Help" Onclick="help()"  >&nbsp;
      <input class="buttons btn" type="button" value="Copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#result"  >&nbsp;
   </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite clear about your question, but please be aware by default, [inline JavaScript will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

You could take a look at [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), then you may determine use some way to relax the default policy, or use script file with some code like `button.addEventListener('click', function(){}, false);` to bind you event.